# Classes annotated with @Mock and @InjectMock coming as null while running the junit test

Tags: junit4, junit5, powermock

Getting Below error while trying to run the below junit test case. Using PowerMockito dependencies and jdk 11:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.mycontroller.controller.TestController.postData()" because "this.testController" is null
            at com.test.ControllerTest.testPostData(ControllerTest.java:31)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
            at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
            at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
            at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
            at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
            at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
            at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
            at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
            at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
            at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
            at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
            at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
            at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Below is the pom dependency I am using for testing:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit5 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.9</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency

>
```

And the code is:

```
    import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
    
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
    import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    
    import com.mycontroller.controller.TestController;
    import com.myservice.service.TestService;
    
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    public class ControllerTest {
    
        @Mock
        TestService testService;
        @InjectMocks
        TestController testController;
    
        @Test
        public void testPostData() {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>("Data saved to DB successfully!!",
                    HttpStatus.CREATED);
            assertEquals(response, testController.postData());
        }
    
    }
```

Just to update, I am not having any constructor in controller class, only autowiring the service class in controller and I am using jdk 11.

Comment: PowerMock is not compatible with Jupiter. You can see that by its requiring the use of RunWith, which does not exist in Jupiter. I suggest you use Mockito's static mocking feature instead - but it's arguably not as powerful.

Comment: If you're interested in the discussion why it probably won't be supported any time soon, have a look at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/201

Comment: Thanks @johanneslink but can you suggest any suitable framework or dependency so that I can run the junit successfully

Comment: As mentioned above, use Mockito‘s static typing feature.